# Export to Excel using phpoffice/phpexcel in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, export, phpexcel, export-to-excel

I want to export my table in database to Excel. I use the `phpoffice/phpexcel` library and the Laravel 5 framework. I have read some articles, but I'm still confused.

How to export a table to Excel using `phpoffice/phpexcel` in Laravel 5?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Maatwebsite](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) wrapper for PHPExcel?

Comment: that one for laravel only

Answer (score -2):

Below are the step to use PHPEXCEL Library with laravel 5

1:- Install "phpoffice" Package in Laravel 5. Below is the link for the packages

2:- Add "phpexcel/phpexcel": "dev-master" to your composer.json. 
Ex:- "require": { "phpexcel/phpexcel": "dev-master" }

3:- Then execute "composer update".

4:- Open the file "/vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php". Paste the below line in the file.

// Include PHPEXCEL Library with Laravel 5 
'PHPExcel' => array($vendorDir . '/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes'),

5:- Now you can use PHPEXCEL library in your controllers or middleware or library.
use PHPExcel; 
use PHPExcel_IOFactory;

For more details you can access "https://github.com/pantlavanya/export-to-excel-using-phpoffice-phpexcel-in-laravel-5" link.

Comment: You find almost the exact same “details” when following the link, because it’s the same text.

Comment: Yes i can't provide more then 1 link here. So I have given full details there in MY GITHUB Repository link and an example of composer.json.         Thanks for reading it.